# Knowledge sharing platform within a company

Tags: knowledge-base

The company where I work is growing quite rapidly and some distance is starting to appears between departments. One of my colleague had to deal with a database project without having any background in the matter. He struggled a lot by his own and ended with something that is working, but poorly designed technically speaking. Once I have been aware of this, I offered him my help (since I do have such background), he was happy about it and we solved many issues together.

This situation seems to me like it will happen again and again in the future as the company is growing .

I am therefore looking for a convenient way to identify and index each people skills, being job related or not, in order to promote mutual assistance.

I think the best solution would be some sort of web based tools where everybody could insert their skills and we could browse the index with search filters (and all the nice feature we are now used to see on a webapp).

Does anybody has something to suggest that could be a nice solution to the problem of knowledge isolation ?

Thanks

Comment: I found a small tool which is free to use for 10 users. You could check if it meets your requirements: http://www.skills-base.com/

Comment: Thanks. This looks like pretty nice tools but it seems to be a little too much "official" versus what I was hoping. I'll keep this in mind !

Comment: I might just go with a straightforward wiki. It is probably not searchable in exactly the way that you want, but is easy to set up & use and lets you share knowledge right there in the wiki.

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint and Yammer are amazing collaboration platforms for enterprises.

At my company we had been using SharePoint for over 10 years, but when we added Yammer then things really got interesting. Collaboration between people spread over various locations became much simpler, effective, transparent.

If your company is MSDN partner you might have free licenses for these products.

Comment: Please include a screenshot showing how people can "insert their skills". Thanks!